# Getting the average values of the previous days value for a given input timestamp in the Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I have an input value to a function as timestamp. I would like to find the
values of particular column(here `impacted_users`) for the previous day's exact timestamp( I need one hour before and after that timestamp values as well).
Based on this I would like to average these values of previous day.

`avg_val_column = avg(val_at_one_hr_before,val_at_one_hr_before,value_at_given_timestamp_yesteday)`

My query is as follows for the current timestamp but I am not sure what would I need to do get the previous days values(&get the avg of those)
Timestamp format: `2022-10-29 11:00:00`

Values to get for `impacted_users` -> `2022-10-28 10:00:00`+ `2022-10-28 11:00:00` + + `2022-10-28 12:00:00`

```
    WITH rc_pt AS (
    SELECT
        procedure_type_rc.timestamp AS timestamp,
        procedure_type_rc.rc_id AS rc_id,
        procedure_type_rc.pt_id AS pt_id,
        procedure_type_rc.impacted_users AS impacted_users,
        -- find avg. of impacted users for previous days values*********
        tmop_comb.stage AS stage
    FROM
        pt_rc AS procedure_type_rc
        INNER JOIN tmop_comb ON procedure_type_rc.rc_id = tmop_comb. "RC"
    WHERE
        procedure_type_rc.timestamp = '{}'
        AND tmop_comb.stage = 1
        AND procedure_type_rc.rc_id IN '{}'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    rc_pt ''.format(self.timestamp, self.nw_rc_ad_tuple)
```

Comment: Can you add some basic `create table` DDL statement for `tmop_comb` and `pt_rc`, plus sample data for them? At first glance it looks like timestamp range type [`tsrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), some `timestamp-'1 day 1 hour'::interval` type of arithmetic and [`avg(impacted_users) over (partition by timeslot)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) might fit your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what your structure is and using [my own test data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8GT1kMLvNgqKSVAAto6k6G/2), but this is to show the idea:

```sql
SELECT
    procedure_type_rc.timestamp AS timestamp,
    procedure_type_rc.rc_id AS rc_id,
    procedure_type_rc.pt_id AS pt_id,
    procedure_type_rc.impacted_users AS impacted_users,
    (   select avg(i.impacted_users) 
        from pt_rc i
            INNER JOIN tmop_comb t ON i.rc_id = t."RC"
        where i.timestamp 
            between '2022-10-28 11:00:00'::timestamp-'1 day 1 hour'::interval
            and '2022-10-28 11:00:00'::timestamp-'23 hours'::interval
        and i.rc_id=procedure_type_rc.rc_id
        and t.stage = 1) as avg_impacted_users_day_before,
    tmop_comb.stage AS stage
FROM
    pt_rc AS procedure_type_rc
    INNER JOIN tmop_comb ON procedure_type_rc.rc_id = tmop_comb."RC"
WHERE
    procedure_type_rc.timestamp = '2022-10-28 11:00:00'
    AND tmop_comb.stage = 1
    AND procedure_type_rc.rc_id IN (1,2,3);
```

All instances of `'2022-10-28 11:00:00'` formatted in as a parameter.

Comment: Can I get this `avg_impacted_users_day_before` based on unique `rc_id and pt_id` combinations? I tried it but got some error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: @sam When you put it like that, it doesn't sound like a big change, but it'll be easier to open a separate question to clarify exactly what you need, than to keep editing the question and the answer in this thread. You can copy test tables and sample data from the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8GT1kMLvNgqKSVAAto6k6G/3) and correct it so that it closely reflects your setup and shows the samples/cases that break things, then show your current query, what you expect it to return and what it returns instead.